# C# vs 13- setup project- where is the db located?

Tags: c#, setup-project

Im new with the setup project and Im trying to understand where is the db located so my app will locate it.

The app have 4 layers : (each of them has a DLL that includes the rest)

1. API - have dll of app level
2. APP level - have dll of BL
3. BL - have dll of DAL
4. DAL- database.

I need to tell the BL layer where is the DB located.

Comment: If you're just starting out, just put the .mdf file in the AppData directory of your project; it's the easiest way to start. And then, setup the connection string in the web.config file.

Comment: What?? where did you read that?

Comment: You tell me its ok to put the db infront of the user?

Comment: Are you talking about a web app or a desktop app? I'm talking about a web app: you can't access the AppData folder from the outside so yes, put the DB in that folder and you're done. If it's a desktop app then I'm not familiar with that particular setup.